# F# parse command line arguments

Tags: f#

I need to get 3 parameters from the command kine (cmd) I wrote the following and got an error:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main(args) = 

   printfn "args: %A" args.[0]
   let xmlP = args.[0]
   let excelFormatP = args.[1]
   let excelP = args.[2]

   printfn "%A" (functionParseXmlToExcel(xmlP , excelFormatP , excelP)) |> ignore

   0
```

I understand that I need to parse the parameters (3 strings).

The error I got when I try to run it from the command line with 3 pathes of files: Index was outside the bounds of the array...

Could someone help me with it??

Thanks

Comment: what is the error you got?

Comment: Thank you: Unhandlad Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array... (- The error in the cmd)

Comment: This is like getting blood from a stone: on what line is the error, and how are you running the code? - if you don't give us enough information to see the problem, how can we fix it?

Comment: You'r right. I tried to run the program from the command line - with the exe file after I compile my F# program. In the command line I wrote:::

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\rivkar>"C:\Users\rivkar\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\XmlToExcel\XmlToExcel\bin\Debug\XmlToExcel.exe" "C:\\Users\\rivkar\\Desktop\\My Projects\\Zmira\\XML2Excel\\NIMO.XML""C:\\Users\\rivkar\\Desktop\\My Projects\\Zmira\\XML2Excel\\nimo2_types.csv" "C:\\Users\\rivkar\\Desktop\\My Projects\\Zmira\\XML2Excel\\"
args: "C:\\Users\\rivkar\\Desktop\\My Projects\\Zmira\\XML2Excel\\NIMO.XML"C:\\Users\\rivkar\\Desktop\\My Projects\\Zmira\\XML2Excel\\nimo2_types.csv"

Comment: and got the following error: Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at XML2Excel.main(String[] args) in C:\Users\rivkar\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\XmlToExcel\XmlToExcel\XML2Excel.fs:line 109

Comment: Do you need something else?  Thanks

Comment: Aside from the non-matching " with a dummy `functionParseXmlToExcel` I get no error.  Please read this and provide sufficient information in the question to recreate the error https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you send me what you run in the cmd? but I got the following error:

Comment: could you please add back your additional info back to the question as an edit, it's difficult to read the comments.

Comment: you can also try and join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f as it's easier to discuss what you want rather then going back and forth with the comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your pasted commandline, it very much looks like you forgot to add a space between your second and third path on the commandline - you have two `""` right next to each other. You should also have noticed that, when printing out the first argument `args.[0]`, you see two paths concatenated by a single `"`

As for making your code more robust: Accessing array elements without first checking the length of the array is a bad idea, whatever the language is. F# provides you with a great way of doing both length check and element access in one swoop, via array pattern matching:

```
match args with
| [| xmlP; excelFormatP; excelP |] ->
    let result = functionParseXmlToExcel(xmlP , excelFormatP , excelP)
    printfn "Completed with %A" result
    0
| _ -> 
    failwithf "Expected 3 commandline arguments, but got %i arguments" args.Length
```

I'd strongly suggest to read up on [pattern matching in general](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/match-expression/) - Scott rightly calls it "the workhorse of F#".

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure how many parameters are you passing, and how you actually parsing them, then how the function that your are calling expects to receive them. So it might be a good idea to show the function signature for `functionParseXmlToExcel` as well. See below for a very simple sample:

```
let myExcelFunction(param1,param2,param3) =
    printfn "%A" param1
    printfn "%A" param2
    printfn "%A" param3


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%A" argv

    let parseParams (argv:string []) =
        let param1,param2,param3 = argv.[0],argv.[1],argv.[2]
        myExcelFunction(param1,param2,param3)

    match argv.Length with
        | 3 -> parseParams argv |> ignore
        | _ ->  failwith "You need to pass three parameters!" 
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

For a more complete solution you might investigate [Argu](http://fsprojects.github.io/Argu/index.html/).